# How do I get NERDCommenter to add comments in a particular column?

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor, macvim, nerdcommenter

NERDCommenter works like this by default:

```
//level1
    //level2
        //level3
```

How do I get to work like this?

```
//level1
//    level2
//        level3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218):

```
[count]<leader>cl  
[count]<leader>cb    |NERDComAlignedComment|
```

> Same as |NERDComComment| except that the delimiters are aligned down
>   the left side (cl) or both sides (cb).

Comment: Is there a way to make that the "default"? i.e. make <leader>c<space> align left.

Comment: There is, but it involves changing 2 lines of the nerdcommenter code. I provided the details in a seperate answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to change the default behaviour of ToggleComment (`<leader>c<space>`) to use left alignment. However this means changing two lines in `$vimfiles/bundle/nerdcommenter/plugin/NERDCommenter.vim` (assuming the usual pathogen setup for managing plugins).

Find the definition of function `function s:CommentLinesToggle`. As the first line add the following to determine the correct indentation index:

`let leftAlignIndx = s:LeftMostIndx(a:forceNested, 0, a:firstLine, a:lastLine)`.

You can now use this index for setting the comment alignment. For this change the line:

`let theLine = s:AddLeftDelim(s:Left({'space': 1}), theLine)` to 
`let theLine = s:AddLeftDelimAligned(s:Left({'space': 1}), theLine, leftAlignIndx)`.

Done. Toggling comments now gives you:

```python
for i in range(10):
    #if i / 2 == 0:
    #    print "Ciao"
print "finito"
```